# Excel VB Code with Input Box to select a range, when nothing is selected it generates and error

Tags: excel, vba

Let me start with the fact that I am NOT a programmer.  I am self taught some VB with Excel and MS Access.  I know just enough to be dangerous.

I have the following code to prompt the user to select a range.  The Input box has an OK and Cancel button.  If you do not select any cells and hit the OK or select Cancel it generates an errors.

```
Private Sub Copy_St5_50_Ramp_Click()
Dim sCell As Range

Set sCell = Application.InputBox("Select the Column of data below that is valid Ramp Data STARTING With 24 Minutes!!!", "Station 5", Type:=8)

If sCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If sCell.Cells.Count < 2 Then Application.InputBox ("You Did not Select Enough Cells"), ("ERROR"), vbOK

sCell.Copy

Worksheets("50 Ramp Data").Range("CJ13").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


'Clear Clipboard (removes "marching ants" around your original data set)
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

Worksheets("50 Ramp Data").Range("L4").Select
End Sub
```

I need it to not error but just close the input box and maybe prompt with a message box as to what went wrong

Comment: add:  on error resume next

Comment: @Keith  have you tried the code in my answer below ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added 2 events to trap the possible errors:

1. If the user hits cancel >> `On Error Resume Next` , and later check `If Err.Number <> 0 Then`.
2. If the user didn't select any cell, use another parameter in the `Application.InputBox` of `Default:=Selection.Address`. So you compare if the `Selection.Address` after the `InputBox` is the same as the `Selection.Address` before the `InputBox`. If it is, then no new selection was made >> abort the operation.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Copy_St5_50_Ramp_Click()

Dim sCell As Range
Dim CurrentSelectionRng As String

CurrentSelectionRng = Selection.Address

On Error Resume Next
Set sCell = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the Column of data below that is valid Ramp Data STARTING With 24 Minutes!!!", Title:="Station 5", Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)

' trap a case when the user selectes "Cancel"
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "You chose cancel !", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

' if the user didn't select anything (but the cell curser stayed on previous selection)
If sCell.Address = CurrentSelectionRng Then
    MsgBox "No cell was selected !", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If sCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If sCell.Cells.Count < 2 Then Application.InputBox ("You Did not Select Enough Cells"), ("ERROR"), vbOK

sCell.Copy

Worksheets("50 Ramp Data").Range("CJ13").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Clear Clipboard (removes "marching ants" around your original data set)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Worksheets("50 Ramp Data").Range("L4").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes I use your example and it solved the problem.  It was just want I needed.  Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: @Keith  you're welcome, please mark as answer , by clicking the little **V** next to my answer